# ECLiPSe predicate for checking if a list contains elements with certain positions in another list

Tags: prolog, logic

My goal is to create a predicate that checks whether a given list contains elements that occupy certain positions in some other list.

More precisely, I'm looking for a predicate which would be true iff a list `L` had elements inside of it which denote rows of an `NxN` array `A` represented by flattened list `C`. For instance if `A = [[0,1],[1,1]], C = [0,1,1,1], L = [1,1], N=2`, then `predicate(L,C,2)` should be true.

My attempt looks as follows (the assumption is that L has at least 2 elements):

```
row([H1,H2|T],C,N) :- M is N*N-N+1, X::1..M, X #= N*_ + 1, 
                      nth1(X,C,H1), Y is X+1, nth1(Y,C,H2),
                      nextr([H2,T],C,Y).

nextr([H1,H2|T],C,Y) :- nth1(Y,C,H1), Z is Y+1, nth1(Z,C,H2), 
                        nextr([H2,T],C,Z).

nextr([H1,H2],C,Y) :- nth1(Y,C,H1), Z is Y+1, nth1(Z,C,H2).
```

`row` predicate makes sure that the first element of `L` takes a position in `C` that denotes a beginning of a new row in array `A` and, additionally, checks that the next element of L is also the next element in `C`. Then, the nextr predicate checks just the latter condition.

To my mind this should work just fine. Sadly -- it doesn't, as `row([0,1],[0,1,1,1],2).` outputs `No` :(

EDIT: Ok, that was a stupid example I noticed. But anyways - it doesn't work on `row([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],1).` bt it outputs `Yes` on `row([1,2|3],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],1).` I don't get it.

I'm rather new to Prolog so excuse me if what I ask is extremely obvious, but I've been thinking about this for the past few hours and couldn't understand what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it. When I write `[H|T]`, then H is an element and `T` is a list. So calling a predicate on `[H,T]` is not equivalent to calling a predicate on `L` which is created by `append(H,T,L)`.

Comment: Yes, you got it. `[H|Hs]` is *very* different from `[H,Hs]`. Confusing the two is common beginners' mistake. For a very simple example, ponder the difference between `[H|[]]` and `[H,[]]`. How many elements are in each of these lists? In how many equivalent *other* ways can you write each of them?